# Are models (as in Backbone or Ampersand models) really necessary with React?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, reactjs, ampersand.js

I come from a Backbone / Marionette background and have been working in React for a few weeks now.  A lot of people say you should pair React with something like Backbone or Ampersand.js, using React as the V and Backbone / Ampersand as the "M" and "C" in the classic MVC model.

However, the more I think about this, the more I wonder if it's really necessary.  In Backbone / Ampersand, the model's main purpose is to track state, and "tell" views to update when the model's state changes.  Of course in React, the view takes care of this responsibility via the view's `props` and `state`, which seems to make a full blown Backbone / Ampersand model unnecessary and duplicative.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let's define model in MVC terms.  The following is from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller).

> [...] the model, captures the behavior of the application [...] independent of the user interface.
>
> The model directly manages the data, logic and rules of the application. A view can be any output representation of information [...] multiple views of the same information are possible [...].
>
> The third part, the controller, **accepts input and converts it to commands for the model** or view.

In React you inevitably will create View+Controller components; much like angular, knockout, and most other JS application frameworks.

#### Why models?

While you could also throw the model into the component at this level, it turns out to not work well in practice. You have problems like overfetching (and other optimization limitations), difficulty testing, no separation of concerns, and it's difficult to see what the component actually is until you mentally separate the controller behavior from the model behavior.

#### So, backbone?

If you have this code, and you want to make it better, you'll eventually end up with models. It could be backbone models, or it could be flux stores, or it could just be simple objects with functions that call $.ajax.

It makes little difference what kind of models you use, but you do need them.

#### MODEL ALL THE THINGS

Woah! Hold on there. Models aren't free. Every time you use a model you're crossing the abstraction boundary, and leaving component land. It's an imperative action in a declarative system, so we need to keep things predictable.

Most of your components are pretty dumb. Props, and maybe some UI state. You have controller components ("View Controllers"), which are 100% tied to your model layer, and you have the rest of the components which are (ideally) 0% tied to your model layer.

What you seem to be describing in the original question is a small application where you have one of these controller components. However as these grow, you need to coordinate between them (not fetching the same user twice, for example). You nest these controllers inside other controllers to build an application. The model is the glue.

Comment: Like the "simple objects with functions that call $.ajax" concept for models.  Seems like a better fit with a React app.

Comment: If you know how to write a simple in-memory cache, and do things like turn arrays into objects with fast lookup by id, it is. There are libraries that try to abstract these, but I feel like it's so situational that prepackaged solutions aren't worth using on projects where the difference between 5ms and 50ms matters (60% maybe?).

Answer (score 1):

You can think of a React component as a functionally pure function that takes *props* and *state* as input arguments.  Its render() method's job is to produce and returns a (virtual) DOM element or JSX (syntactic sugar) based on *props* and *state*.  Backbone still "owns" the model.  When the Backbone model changes via user inputs or socket events or whatever,  *setState*() can be called (add some magic here) which causes React components to render again.  The point is React component does not hold the state.  This is NOT to say that one must uses Backbone with React as React is simply a rendering library.

**Update**: In *[react-future](https://github.com/reactjs/react-future)*, it's very clear that *render*() should be treated as a pure function.  It takes *props* and *state* as input arguments and its job is to produce a JXS, so no need to refer to the *this* keyword.

https://github.com/reactjs/react-future/blob/master/01%20-%20Core/01%20-%20Classes.js

Comment: "The point is [the] React component does not hold state."  "Holding state" is exactly what the React component is supposed to do no?

Comment: I would refrain from storing state in a component https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/interactivity-and-dynamic-uis.html.  From this paraprah "A common pattern is to create several stateless components...", the stateful component can be potentially substituted by your BB or ampersand models.